# Reducing GPS coldstart if we know where the user is

Tags: gps

I'm working on a project with GPS and I was wondering if it would be possible to reduce the cold start time by passing in some data. Let's say I already had a fairly good idea of where the user was because this GPS was to be used only in a certain theme park. Could I pass in that data and reduce the cold start time? If so on which chipset would it be easiest to implement and how?

Comment: The cold start is caused by not knowing which satellites will be used, having satellite trajectory information and a course location can reduce it by a factor 10 or more. Usually upto 30 days of trajectory can be pre-calculated and used. Mobile phones do that using your data subscription, my camera does that by a pre-loaded assist file.

Comment: There are three things that will speed up an assisted start: Satellite orbits, valid for a day or so, your approximate position, and a good estimate of the current time. Read the uBlox datasheets for a description of what they offer, and how it helps.

Answer (score 1):

thats what we call AGPS, however what the receiver needs are the satellite orbits not doing a coordinate adjustment, that data can be obtained directly from the satellites, however you will have the cold start, or they can be obtained from servers which have that data stored. if your receiver supports AGPS you will be able to do this easily most likely